# Writing an infinitely running( while(true) { } ) user input function in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a lexer in Haskell. For easy console input and output, I've used an intermediate data type **Transition Table**.

```
type TransitionTable = [(Int, Transitions String Int)]
type Transitions a b = [(a, b)]
```

I want to take input from the user for all the states and transitions. I do not want to take the total number of states before hand. I want it to keep taking input for the transitions of each state until the user types *"--"* . If the user types *"---"*, the current state is discarded and the input terminates.

After a lot of attempts I came up with this, which I think is horrible code.

```
-- |A function to emulate the while loop for easy IO functionality.
--  Defination:- while @comparator @func @start:
--      *comparator @arg: A function which returns True or False on the basis of @arg.
--          The loop stops when False is returned.
--      *func: The function which is executed repeadly.
--          It is responsible for returning the next @arg for the comparator on the basis of the current @arg.
--      *start: The starting value of @arg to pass to the comparator.
while :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
while comparator func start =
    if comparator start then do
        nxt <- func start
        while comparator func nxt
    else
        return start

-- |A modification of putStr which flushes out stdout. Corrents buffer problems.
myPutStr :: String -> IO ()
myPutStr str = putStr str >> hFlush stdout >> return ()
```

---

```
-- Takes input from the console to generate a TransitionTable.
inputTransitionTable :: IO TransitionTable
inputTransitionTable = do
    putStrLn "Type -- for next state and --- for completing input entering."
    retVal <- while notFinished takeInfo (0, [])
    return (snd retVal)
        where
            -- Returns True when input entry is over.
            notFinished (i, _) = i > -1

            -- Takes the current state number and the incomplete corrosponding transition table which is populated 
            -- with user input. Input ends when user enters "---". State number is set to -1 when input is over.
            takeInfo (i, states) = do
                putStrLn ("Adding transitions to state " ++ show i ++ ": ")
                retVal <- while entryNotFinished takeStateInfo ("", [])
                let (inpStr, stateInfo) = retVal
                case inpStr == "---" of
                    True -> return (-1, states)
                    False -> return (i+1, states ++ [(i, stateInfo)])

            -- Checks if input entry is over. Returns False if finished.
            entryNotFinished (s, _)
                | s == "--" || s == "---"  =  False
                | otherwise  =  True

            -- Takes the input state number along with the corresponding transitions.
            -- Input ends when the user enters "--".
            takeStateInfo (str, state_info) = do
                myPutStr "\tEnter transitions symbol: "
                symbol <- getLine
                if symbol == "--" || symbol == "---" then
                    return (symbol, state_info)
                else do
                    myPutStr "\t\tEnter the transition state number: "
                    state' <- getLine
                    let state = read state' :: Int
                    return (str, (symbol, state):state_info)
```

Basically this is how it runs:

```
*Main> x <- inputTransitionTable
Type -- for next state and --- for completing input entering.
Adding transitions to state 0: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 1
    Enter transitions symbol: b
        Enter the transition state number: 2
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 1: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 2
    Enter transitions symbol: b
        Enter the transition state number: 3
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 2: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 3
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 3: 
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 4:
    Enter transitions symbol: ---
(0.03 secs, 344420 bytes)

-- Output
*Main> prettyPrintTransitionTable x
State   Transitions
0  ("b",2)  ("a",1)
1  ("b",3)  ("a",2)
2  ("a",3)
3
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is a cleaner way to write it!

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import System.IO

type TransitionTable = [(Int, Transitions String Int)]
type Transitions a b = [(a, b)]

inputTransitionTable :: IO TransitionTable
inputTransitionTable = execWriterT $ runMaybeT $ forM_ [0..] $ \i -> do
    -- Monad transformer stack at this point is:
    -- MaybeT                      <= Outer loop
    --    (WriterT TransitionTable <= Outer writer
    --        IO ) r
    let liftIO    = lift . lift
        tellOuter = lift . tell
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Adding transitions to state " ++ show i ++ ": "
    t <- execWriterT $ runMaybeT $ forever $ do
        -- Monad transformer stack at this point is:
        -- MaybeT                                <= Inner loop
        --    (WriterT (Transitions String Int)  <= Inner writer
        --        (MaybeT                        <= Outer loop
        --            (WriterT TransitionTable   <= Outer writer
        --                 IO ) ) ) r
        let liftIO     = lift . lift . lift . lift
            breakOuter = lift . lift $ mzero
            tellInner  = lift . tell
            breakInner = mzero
        liftIO $ putStr "\tEnter transitions symbol: "
        symbol <- liftIO getLine
        case symbol of
            "--"  -> breakInner
            "---" -> breakOuter
            _     -> return ()
        liftIO $ putStr "\t\tEnter the transition state number: "
        state' <- liftIO getLine
        tellInner [(symbol, read state')]
    tellOuter [(i, t)]

prettyPrintTransitionTable table
  = forM_ table $ \(n, transitions) -> do
        putStr $ show n ++ " "
        forM_ transitions $ \(symbol, state) -> do
            putStr $ "{" ++ symbol ++ "→" ++ show state ++ "} "
        putStrLn ""

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- <= Auto-flushes all "putStr"s
    t <- inputTransitionTable
    prettyPrintTransitionTable t
```

The following is how I would actually write it in my own code, so you can compare the size of the code a fluent Haskell programmer writes and compare to your favorite language:

```
inputTransitionTable = execWriterT $ runMaybeT $ forM_ [0..] $ \i -> do
    let liftIO = lift . lift
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Adding transitions to state " ++ show i ++ ": "
    t <- execWriterT $ runMaybeT $ forever $ do
        let liftIO     = lift . lift . lift . lift
        liftIO $ putStr "\tEnter transitions symbol: "
        symbol <- liftIO getLine
        case symbol of
            "--"  -> mzero
            "---" -> lift . lift $ mzero
            _     -> return ()
        liftIO $ putStr "\t\tEnter the transition state number: "
        state' <- liftIO getLine
        lift $ tell [(symbol, read state')]
    lift $ tell [(i, t)]
```

Test output from the program:

```
./transitions
Adding transitions to state 0:
        Enter transitions symbol: a
                Enter the transition state number: 1
        Enter transitions symbol: b
                Enter the transition state number: 2
        Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 1: 
        Enter transitions symbol: a
                Enter the transition state number: 2
        Enter transitions symbol: b
                Enter the transition state number: 3
        Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 2: 
        Enter transitions symbol: a
                Enter the transition state number: 3
        Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 3: 
        Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 4: 
        Enter transitions symbol: ---
0 {a→1} {b→2} 
1 {a→2} {b→3} 
2 {a→3} 
3
```

If you don't know very much about monad transformers, the best starting point is [this paper](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.pdf).  Don't be put off by the fact that it's a paper.  It's written towards beginners and it's very readable and understandable.

To understand the trick I use for breaking out of loops, I recommend you read [this post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html) explaining how you can use `MaybeT` and `EitherT` to easily break from loops on the fly the same way you would in an imperative language.

Also, note that I use the `WriterT` monad transformer to collect results.  `WriterT` commonly arises any time you need to fold or collect data interactively.

I use `hSetBuffering` to set the output buffering to auto-flush everything.  This is an alternative to writing your own `putStr` function.

I want to also point out the nice `forM_` combinator which you can use to mimic `foreach` in other languages.  I show it off in the pretty printer function to write code that is almost indistinguishable from the equivalent imperative code.

Also, if you are new to monad transformers, I recommend you stick to the `transformers` library whenever possible and try to use the `mtl` only sparingly.  This means using `Control.Monad.Trans.Class` instead of `Control.Monad.Trans` and `Control.Monad.Trans.XXX` for the monad transformers.  The need to manually `lift` things might seem off-putting at first, but you gain the ability to equationally reason about your code.  That might not seem like much to you now, but as you become a better Haskell programmer you will value that a lot more, so it's a good habit to build early on.

Answer (score 2):

In order to repeat an action ad nauseum, you can use [`forever`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aforever). But you don't really need to use that here, you can just do it the way you've done it so far. Though I'd think that your `while` function could be written with guards instead.

```
while :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
while comparator func start | comparator start = func start >>= while comparator func
                            | otherwise        = return start
```

You could also look into using
[`Control.Monad.LoopWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loop-while),
though I've never used it before.

Note that you don't need `>> return ()`, since `hFlush :: Handle -> IO ()` already returns `()` in the `IO` Monad. Actually, you never really need `return ()`. I find it preferable to use `void action` or `_ <- action` in order to throw away the result of `action`.

Your `inputTransitionTable` function is… not very idiomatic. Threading state
yourself is unnecessary, you can use the `State` monad.

Instead of this interactive process, it might actually be easier for a user to
just specify the transition table as a list of ordered pairs, pretty much the
way you're printing it after the thing is done. This would probably also require
you to *parse* the user input properly, which is good opportunity to learn the
ropes with `parsec`. If you want to keep the interactive model, then I'd
recommend stacking the `IO` and `State` Monads together into an action of type
`State IO TransitionTable`.

You can read up on all this stuff in the corresponding chapters of
*RealWorldHaskell*. [Chapter 16 on
Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html), and [Chapter
18 on Monad
Transformers](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html).